# Inner product of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology

Suppose $A_{ij}\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a symmetric non-degenerate real matrix. I am studying the set of polynomials $F^{i_1\cdots i_m}\in\mathbb{R}[x^1,\dots,x^n]$ (antisymmetric in the upper indices) such that
$$0=x^iA_{ii_1}F^{i_1\cdots i_m}.$$
In particular, a rather obvious choice is $F^{i_1\cdots i_m}=x^kA_{kj}G^{ji_1\cdots i_m}$, for some polynomials $G^{ji_1\cdots i_m}\in\mathbb{R}[x^1,\dots,x^n]$. I want to show that this is the only possibility.

I believe that the formulation of this problem in the language of algebraic geometry would be to prove that the Koszul complex of the regular sequence given by the hyperplanes $x^iA_{ij}$ has zero cohomology in degrees different than $0$ (see page 20 of [Factorization algebras and free field theories](https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Egwilliam/thesis.pdf)).

Comment: The fact about the Koszul complex of a regular sequence is standard and proven e.g. in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koszul_complex#Properties_of_a_Koszul_homology But I don't understand your first formulation of the problem. Is that Einstein summation notation and if so what is the relationship between the lower index $j$ and the upper indices $i_1 \dots i_m$?

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing the link out to me. Yes, I was using Einstein summation  notation and I had a misplaced index which I just corrected. I will take a look at the proof in Wikipedia and maybe post an answer in this notation.

Comment: Also, when you say a polynomial "antisymmetric in the upper polynomials," given your reference to a Koszul complex, do you really mean an element of the exterior algebra?

Comment: Yes, again that was a typo. I meant antisymmetric in the upper indices. In the language of the Wikipedia article, I have $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, $E=R^n$, and $s_i=A_{ij}x^j$. My original formulation of the problem was just an index-full version of the statement that every closed element (in non zero degree) of the Koszul complex is exact.